# iOS - How to use mkmapview as location picker

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

In my app I have two address UITextfields to be filled up using address text. I want this behavior:

- As soon as user enters address textfield, a map appears from down. (already done)
- User plays with the map. As he does that, a floating annotation object appears which is just about to drop.
- A button (a subview of mkmapview), when pressed, drops this floating annotation on to the map.
- As soon as user presses Done button, the annotation location on the map is reverse-geocoded.
- The map view disappears (already done).
- The UITextfield is populated with address text corresponding to center of the map view.
- Same is repeated for another UITextfield.

I believe this is a very straight use case of mkmapview. But can't find any examples of this already done.
Am I missing something pretty obvious in UIKit?

Many thanks for your help....

**EDIT:**

I read up [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW25), and I found many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging) that point towards this.
However all of them seems to assume that MKPinAnnotationView (or MKAnnotationView) is overridden.

Is it necessary?
If yes, how much I need to provide in the subclass apart from dragging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to subclass `MKPinAnnotationView`. Just use it. You only should be subclass it if you're looking for some custom behavior. But it is useful to write a `viewForAnnotation` so you can configure it properly. But typically I find the configuration of a standard `MKPinAnnotationView` to be simple enough that no subclassing is needed:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"DroppedPin"];

    annotationView.draggable = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;

    return annotationView;
}
```

---

Having said that, it is not uncommon to have your own annotation class. I might do this for at least two reasons:

1. You might keep the reverse geocoded `MKPlacemark` as a property of your annotation. Logically, the geocoded information seems like a property of the annotation, not of the view. You can then inquire this `placemark` property of the dropped pin to get whatever information you need to pass back to your other view.
2. If you want, you could configure your annotation to both perform the reverse geocode lookup which would the `placemark` property, but also change the title to the reverse geocoded address when you change its `coordinate`, too. This way, the user is getting active feedback about what the reverse geocoding as they're dragging and dropping the pin on the map, but the code is still super simple:

Thus, you might have an annotation class like:

```
@interface DroppedAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, strong) MKPlacemark *placemark;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;

@end

@implementation DroppedAnnotation

- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude
                                                      longitude:coordinate.longitude];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        // do whatever you want here ... I'm just grabbing the first placemark

        if ([placemarks count] > 0 && error == nil)
        {
            self.placemark = placemarks[0];

            NSArray *formattedAddressLines = self.placemark.addressDictionary[@"FormattedAddressLines"];
            self.title = [formattedAddressLines componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
        }
    }];

    _coordinate = coordinate;
}

@end
```

And your view controller can use this new class:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MKAnnotation> droppedAnnotation;

- (void)dropPin
{
    // if we've already dropped a pin, remove it

    if (self.droppedAnnotation)
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.droppedAnnotation];

    // create new dropped pin

    DroppedAnnotation *annotation = [[DroppedAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
    annotation.title = @"Dropped pin"; // initialize the title
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    self.droppedAnnotation = annotation;
}
```

To be clear, you don't *need* your own annotation class. You could use the standard `MKPointAnnotation` for example. But then your view controller has to keep call and keep track of reverse geocoded information itself. I just think the code is a little cleaner and more logical when you use a custom annotation class.

Comment: Shall I upvote it for say +100? You just answered 3 of my forthcoming SO questions! While I am yet to try it myself, this quite clears up so many confusions. Hats off for such a concise explanation!

Comment: still don't understand why you discard droppedAnnotation. Also, why willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey?

Comment: @NiravBhatt 1. Why discard `droppedAnnotation`? I assumed a UI like the Maps app, where if you drop a another pin, it would remove the prior dropped pin. If you want multiple dropped pins, you don't have to remove the prior ones (though you'd want to keep an array of the pins you've been dropping rather than a single `droppedAnnotation`). 2. Why `willChange...` and `didChange...`? This is part of KVO, which is default behavior for class setters. You don't technically need to do that, but if you're writing custom setters, it's good practice. You'll thank yourself when you get into KVO.

Comment: Aah right. For this particular use case I would rather want single annotation (pre-existing when the map appears - like a global singleton). User can drag-drop it whatever times, but no addition to the map view. I suppose I would need some flag-gates around addAnnotation code here. And yes, KVO is unknown territory for me, I would read up the docs, glad you mentioned.

Comment: Two things: firstly, all I have is single annotation for my current user location which I would like to drag-drop leisurely. I successfully got it using your class. While it drag-drops OK, I don't see setCoordinate() being called. As a result, title keeps showing "Current Location" instead of reverse-geocoded string. Secondly, I don't think I need dropPin method because all I have is single annotation which gets added due to mapview.showsuserlocation = YES. What I need however is the title property when it drops, or maybe when the user taps OK button of the accessory view toolbar. Possible?

Comment: @NiravBhatt let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26323/discussion-between-rob-and-nirav-bhatt)